# How can i handle the " time gap" between the end of standard time and beggining of daylight summer time

Tags: javascript, sql-server, date, datetime, timestamp

I have an app where the users will make appointments. I want to avoid errors on the making appointment part with the DST - daylight summer time.

**Lets talk a bit about the flow:**

Today is 23:03:2021 and the user goes on my app, he makes appointment for example on 25:03:2021 at 13:00.I get the request made from him, and i write in my DB the date and time in timestamp UTC that maked appointment.

Also i am showing the maked appointments at the user screen - for example you have an appointment on xx at xx...

**The problem is:**

I am in `Europe/Warsaw` timezone` and currently i am in +01 from the UTC.

On the last Sunday in March - 28:03:2021 - there is DST - daylight summer time and the clock goes forward one hour.
That means that i will be +02 from UTC.

Now let's say that some user will make event on 29:03:2021 at 15:00.He makes the appointment `NOW 23 date` when the time is `standard` ( the actual request ), but actually the date and time that he choosed in the `FUTURE` - are in `DAYLIGHT SUMMER TIME`.

So when 29:03:2021 comes - i need to show him that he has an appointment at 15:00 - everyhing okay. The time will be forwarded one hour at his clock.He comes to the appointment at 15:00...

But what if i have the event between the ending of the standard time and the starting of the daylight summer timer - for example

```
// FIRST
var miliseconds = 59;
var date = new Date(2021, 02, 27, 25, 59, miliseconds, 0);
console.log(date);
var res = isDST(date);
console.log(res);
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());

console.log('------')
// vs
// SECOND
var miliseconds = 60;
var date = new Date(2021, 02, 27, 25, 59, miliseconds, 0);
console.log(date);
var res = isDST(date);
console.log(res);
console.log(date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

executing this java script code we can see that in the first case for the date we have output

```
Sun Mar 28 2021 01:59:59 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
false ( it is not DST )
- 60 ( OFFSET )
```

so increasing one milisecond - gives not 02:00 - but will give 03:00

so the output is

```
Sun Mar 28 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) ( NOTICE +02 UTC NOW NOT 01 LIKE THE FIRST CASE )
true
-120
```

and let's say for example he maked appointment on 23:03:2021 ( the actual request ) that he wants an appointment on 28:03:2021 at 02:15 hour

Which actually does not 'exist' in this gap between end of standard and start of daylight summer time.

how can i handle this situation ?

SO if he choose 02:00 then before the request is maked and saved in db, we should make that automatically 03:00 automatically and notice the user about that ?

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't be storing the data in UTC here, if I am honest. Appointment times are local, so should be *assumed* to be the time specific to that day. Rather that storing the appointment is at 13:00 UTC, they should be selecting that it is at 15:00 on that day. Then it doesn't matter if DST is being observed or not, as for the "locals" 15:00 is15:00.

Comment: @Larnu Not sure I agree.  Having users in many time zones, UTC is the great equalizer.  It is a small matter to toggle between Juliet (local) and Zulu (UTC)  on the client side.   For example:   new Date('2021-03-23 17:02:54.997'+' UTC')  returns  Tue Mar 23 2021 10:02:54 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Comment: There are both pros, and cons, to storing in UTC, @JohnCappelletti . I don't see that the OP suggests that they are dealing with multiple timezones (unless I missed someone) so storing the local time seems more logical here.

Comment: You could write a book on this, but briefly, do everything in UTC. If the event is in a particular location, store the appropriate IANA representative location (e.g. Europe/Warsaw) along with the event. Make users aware of the offset/timezone being used when displaying times and dates. ECMAScript dates will easily go from Date to any timezone, much more difficult to create a Date for a specific date and time in a particular timezone. A library will help greatly there. Dealing with the missing time going into DST and the double time out of DST is an issue for another question…

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that.  Recurring events *can not* be stored in terms of UTC, because they have to contend with offset changes between occurrences.  Singular events can, but only if you are willing to speculate that the government won't change the time zone offset or DST rules between when you schedule it and when the event takes place.  Local time works in both situations, but only if you have some way to disambiguate between first and second occurrence in a fall-back scenario.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint— "*only if you are willing to speculate that the government won't change the … rules*". Yep, many places in Europe are reconsidering DST as the [EU drops DST in 2021](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/mar/26/european-parliament-votes-to-scrap-daylight-saving-time-from-2021), leaving it to member nations whether they continue with it, go to standard time or adopt DST all year round.

Comment: I don't understank you Larnu.My problem is that even in local time, there is one hour gap between the end of standard and start of summer time...

Comment: So anyone can suggest what can man do with this one hour gap in between please ?

Comment: – RobG @– RobG It is not a issue for another question.That was my actual question man,,,